# How can I accept only numbers from an edit control?

Tags: delphi, exception

Normally I would do the following to save a string value into the database

```
DataModule.tbTableNumber.Value := StrToFloat(edtNumber.text);
```

Now the problem comes when the user enters something that cannot convert to a number. How would I be able to prevent this? Can a person use an exception and how would I write this exception?

I'm using Delphi XE2.

Comment: Why you are not using the data-aware controls? like [Vcl.DBCtrls.TDBEdit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TDBEdit)

Comment: An alternate approach would be to prevent the user from entering invalid data in the first place. You could use a control that supports input masks or you could handle the `TEdit.OnChange` event to prevent the user from entering non-numeric data. `TEdit` also has a `NumbersOnly` property but it won't prevent the user from copying and pasting invalid data into the field.

Comment: What benefit will a data-aware control give me over a normal TEdit

Comment: Many benefits, between them the entry data validation is made for the control it self depending of the type of the field, So if you bind a TDbEdit to  an integer or float field, the control only allow enter numeric values.

Comment: So if a TEdit is connected to a number filed, it will refuse to take any other characters that is not numeric?

Comment: @Japster Yes, but this is valid for a TDbEdit not TEdit .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best solution (IMHO) is to use `TryStrToFloat`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myfloat: double;
begin
  if TryStrToFloat(Edit1.Text, myfloat) then
    DataModule.tbTableNumber.Value := myfloat
  else
    ShowMessage('Incorrect value.');
end;
```

I don't think it is particularly 'clean' to use a `try..except` when when the error is as trivial and, in fact, as expected, as in this case.

Comment: @Japster: The result of the string-to-float conversion is saved in `myfloat`, that is, `TryStrToFloat(S, F)` tries to convert the string `S` into a floating-point number. If it succeeds, it returns `true` and the result is saved in `myfloat`. If not, it returns `false`.

Comment: @Andreas: fully agreed that Exception should be used for exceptional cases, not when there is such a good chance of it happening so routinely.

Answer (score 5):

You can catch the exception with the following

```
  try
    val := StrToFloat(edtNumber.text);
  except
    on E: EConvertError do
    begin
      ShowMessage( 'Entered Data is not a valid Floating Point number' );
    end;
  end;
```

You might also want to look at

```
StrToFloatDef( edtNumber.text, -1 )
```

If you just need to ensure you convert returns a valid number

Comment: what does the StrToFloatDef( edtNumber.text, -1 ) do exactly

Comment: it returns the passed in default value -1 in this case, if the string does not represent a valid number

Comment: There's also `TryStrToFloat(edtNumber.Text, val)`

Comment: What does this TryStrToFloat funtion do

Comment: Thanks guys you have helped me solve something I have been trying for long :-D

Comment: Japster, you seem to be having trouble reading [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/). It could have told you what StrToFloatDef and TryStrToFloat do.

Answer (score 1):

There are many controls which can be told only to accept numeric input, and this has some benefits over the approach you accepted as your answer.

The [jedi JVCL library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/?_test=b) for example includes several numeric input controls and the basic VCL includes a few possibilities, including the Spin Edit control which is for input of integer values.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution on
http://www.festra.com/eng/snip05.htm

( code from link )

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if not (Key in [#8, '0'..'9', '-', DecimalSeparator]) then begin
    ShowMessage('Invalid key: ' + Key);
    Key := #0;
  end
  else if ((Key = DecimalSeparator) or (Key = '-')) and 
      (Pos(Key, Edit1.Text) > 0) then begin
    ShowMessage('Invalid Key: twice ' + Key);
    Key := #0; 
  end
  else if (Key = '-') and (Edit1.SelStart <> 0) then begin
    ShowMessage('Only allowed at beginning of number: ' + Key);
    Key := #0;
  end;
end;
```